# Positioning summary on the right

Tags: html, css

I would like to position the `summary` on the right as in the example. Using calculated `margin-left` is an option but not ideal.
Is there a better solution?

```css
summary {
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
  width: 15em;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-left: calc(100% - 15em);
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>System Requirements</summary>
  <p>
    Requires a computer running an operating system. The computer must have some
    memory and ideally some kind of long-term storage. An input device as well
    as some form of output device is recommended.
  </p>
</details>
```

Answer (score 0):

`position details relative` then position `summary absolute` with `right: 0;` then `float the p` to `right` after you give a proper `width`.

I hope this is what you want.

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

details {
  position: relative;
}

summary {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 15em;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

p {
padding-top: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>System Requirements</summary>
  <p>
    Requires a computer running an operating system. The computer must have some memory and ideally some kind of long-term storage. An input device as well as some form of output device is recommended.
  </p>
</details>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it can be done using the `float: right` property and applying `clear` on the `p` tag

```css
summary{
  float: right;
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
  width: 15em;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
p{
  clear: right;
  padding: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>System Requirements</summary>
  <p>
    Requires a computer running an operating system. The computer must have some
    memory and ideally some kind of long-term storage. An input device as well
    as some form of output device is recommended.
  </p>
</details>
```

Comment: `float` is a possibility that I also tried but it requires addition CSS `clear` & `padding` or `margin` to make it resemble the original layout of `details/summary`.

Comment: yup that's the case, but still you don't have to calculate the margin as per the content as done originally in the question.